# Minus-symbol in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]Easy qustion I hope (even I cannot find the answer elsewhere): I am working on a Cordova/Ionic/AngularJS project in Visual Studio 2015, which originates from Webstorm on a Mac.

I.e. next to to plugins I see a red "minus symbol". What does it mean, respectively how to get rid of it?

EDIT 1: Picture added.

EDIT 2: Strange thing is: The plugins seem to work... How can it be assuming that a minus symbol means to have files excluded from the project?

Comment: If it's next to a file in a project/solution, it means that file is excluded from the build (i.e. it is part of the project/solution, but it is not compiled). However I'm not sure if this applies to plugins?

Comment: A picture might be helpful here.

Comment: It looks like the symbol added for files in your GitIgnore file to be excluded from source control. I suspect these plugins are installed using a task runner/package manager during build and are automatically restored by Visual Studio when you open the project (similar to NuGet packages). If you could share the contents of your GitIgnore file, that would allow us to validate this possibility.

Comment: They are not part of your project. Right-click, "Include In Project" if you want them to be. Or disable "Show ALl Files" in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the symbol added for files in your GitIgnore file to be excluded from source control. I suspect these plugins are installed using a task runner/package manager during build and are automatically restored by Visual Studio when you open the project (similar to NuGet packages).

If you open your .gitIgnore file in an editor you'll probably have an entry in there that looks like:

```
/plugins
```